# Multiple UI's in one class

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Ok, i know that similar questions have been asked before, but hear me out.
I'm making an application that does simple transformations to an image. I need a ui form for the main window and one for the toolbar. I know that the toolbar should have it's own class but, if i do it like that, it wont be able to change the image that is stored in the MainWindow (right?).

Should i make a class that inherits QGraphicsScene (which holds the image), include it in the toolbar class and include that to the MainWindow, or there is an easier way?

Comment: You can nest widgets into widgets as much as you want. I don't see what's the problem here...

Comment: I guess you mean creating the whole thing in one form, which i can't believe i didn't think of. Thanks.

Comment: You can have them be separate widget elements, and still create another widget and put it all in there. This way it will be easier to maintain.

Comment: You are totally right. For some reason i was convinced the singals/slots connections should be in the widgets' class.